# Adding getter method inhibits parsing when value starts with digit

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to unmarshal xml content like this:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Node.class);
        
String input = "<item><d>foo</d></item>";
StreamSource istream = new StreamSource(new StringReader(input));
JAXBElement<Node> node = context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(istream, Node.class);
System.out.println(node.getValue().toString());
```

The `d` element cannot be trivially converted into the desired object, *here a Boolean*, so I use a setter method for that.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement(name = "item")
public class Node {

    @XmlElement(name = "d") 
    private Boolean value;

    public void setValue(String d) {
        this.value = d.equals("") ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
    }
        
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

The `XmlAnnotaion` can be at `setValue` as well however when I add a getter method it has to be at the field(otherwise there is no parse and `value` remains `null`).

```
public Boolean getValue() {return value;}
```

But if instead of `foo` the value starts with a digit or a special character, say `?`, there is again no parse.

#### Summary of effects:

annotation at field + no getter -> parses `foo`
annotation at setter + no getter -> parses `foo` and `0foo`
annotation at field + getter ->  parses `foo`
annotation at setter + getter -> parses neither

How do I need do set the annotations so that I can parse arbitrary values in `d` and why does it work here for strings that start with a letter?

Answer (score 0):

Because XML is a typed language, and the types of the getter and setter need to match.

If. this is like, a real thing you're getting paid to do then you need to go and spend some time reading the [jaxb documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/xml/jaxb/index.html) and probably the [xml schema documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_documentation.asp).

here's some code because why not.

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "item")
public class Node {

    private Boolean value;

    @XmlElement(name = "d", nillable = true, required = false)
    public void setValue(String d) {
        this.value = "".equals(d) ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    public String getValue(String d) {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    public boolean isValue() {
        return Boolean.TRUE.equals(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[Node|value=" + value + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Node.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Node node = (Node) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader("<item><b></b></item>"));
            System.out.println(node);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```